# UIPageControl not calling selector on valueChanged

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am attempting to use a `UIPageControl` for the first time and I can't seem to get it to call a function on `UIControlEventValueChanged`. Am I missing something here? I even tried a storyboard implementation but same broken results. I tried `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and other actions as well. None are calling the `changePage:` function below.

In the .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPageControl *introPageControl;
-(IBAction)changePage:(id)sender;
```

In the .m:

```
@synthesize introPageControl;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.introPageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,208,self.view.frame.size.width,36)];
    self.introPageControl.numberOfPages = 4;
    self.introPageControl.currentPage = 0;
    [self.introPageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:self.introPageControl];
}

-(IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
    // NEVER GETS CALLED :(
}
```

Comment: i copy paste your code and see that changePage methods called. Could you please provide more details? May be you add another subview above your page control?

Comment: Or may be you unsubscribe from events?

Comment: @AlexanderMerchi thanks for your reply. self.introPageControl is the last object added, thus its on the uppermost level. How would I check for unsubscribing from events? I never added explicit code to do this.

Comment: I creat empty project and these code work. I checked in ios 4.3, ios 5.1, ios 6.1.......

Comment: Could you please try UIControlEventTouchUpInside event for check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UIControlEventValueChanged is only called when the UIPageControl view object was tapped.

Comment: What do you mean by "tabbed"? Do you mean "tapped"? I'm having a similar issue, but tapping the control has no effect.

Comment: Found my problem - my page control was too small. It seems that page controls only respond to taps either to the left or right of the dots. Tapping the dots themselves has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3:**

```
pageControl.numberOfPages = 6
pageControl.currentPage = 0
pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pageControlTapHandler(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

...

func pageControlTapHandler(sender:UIPageControl) {
    print("currentPage:", sender.currentPage) //currentPage: 1
}
```